Import Pandas in MetaEditor5 Python Script
I am trying to write a python script for a trading bot. I have opened up MetaEditor5 and I have created a new python script where the next pop-up asks me which packages I want to import and only offers:
TensorFlow
Numpy
DateTime
Matplotlib
I would like to also have pandas but I am unsure of how to install the package in MetaEditor5. In Spyder I can just type "pip install pandas" in the terminal but I am unsure of how to do it in MetaEditor5.
I am able to run my Python scripts from Spyder normally and execute trades as I wish on the MetaQuotesDemo account but as soon as I go through a broker it does not work.
I am now trying to have the python scripts directly in MetaEditor but I am using pandas which I don't know how to install in MetaEditor5.
I am not sure if this will fix my problem but I want to try it and see.
Can somebody please assist me?
Many thanks.
